# Unity/C# - Input.GetMouseButton not calling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a really annoying problem in Unity where Input.GetMouseButton(0), in both the Update() and Fire() functions, won't call when I am moving my player around the screen. If the player is stationary and I hold the mouse down, it returns true and any code I have afterwards is called.

If I fire while stationary and then start moving while continuing to fire, I won't stop firing or be unable to move.

I also tried using `if (Input.GetAxis("Fire1") !=0)` instead but there was no change.

```
void Update()  
{  
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))  
        Debug.Log("Mouse Pressed");  // Not called when player is moving

    mouseScreenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    Fire(m_gunType);

    PerformRotation();

    PerformMovement();
}

private void PerformMovement()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        m_rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, m_speed * Time.deltaTime));
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        m_rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-m_speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        m_rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, -m_speed * Time.deltaTime));
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        m_rb.AddForce(new Vector2(m_speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
}

private void Fire(GunType gt)
{
    Debug.Log("Fire called"); // Called every frame

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Fired"); // Only called when player is stationary

        // Spawn bullet code
    }
}


private void PerformRotation()
{
    // if m_firePointOffset if changed in the inspector
    if (m_firePoint.localPosition != (Vector3)m_firePointOffset)
        m_firePoint.localPosition = (Vector3)m_firePointOffset;

    // Get Angle in Radians
    float AngleRad = Mathf.Atan2(mouseScreenPosition.y - transform.position.y, mouseScreenPosition.x - transform.position.x);
    // Get Angle in Degrees
    float AngleDeg = (180 / Mathf.PI) * AngleRad;
    // Rotate Object
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, AngleDeg);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem. Is this the full code? If not, maybe post more. Also, take all needed components and put them into a new project or scene and test there. Often it is something unrelated that's causing problems. But specifically, the GetMouseButton method itself won't be causing any problems if polled from Update.

Comment: Apart from the variables and the PerformRotation() that's the only code in the script. I will re-create in a new project and hope it's just a one off occurrence.

Comment: @MarkInnes I really want to see your `PerformRotation()` code. If possible try to run this code in a new project not new scene.

Comment: I've added my `PerformRotation()` code and re-created in a new project but the bug still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours spent on this exact problem, I realized that the problem comes from Windows, not Unity. On any modern Windows version, the touchpad buttons are deactivated if any key is pressed.

To solve the issue, simply go to Touchpad Settings, and set it to sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too what I did is replace my `GetMouseButton` and `GetKey` by `GetKeyDown` and made a void that specially cancels every input you set before when the key is released, then added it to the `void  Update()`
For example,

```
private void PerformMovement()
{
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
  m_rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, m_speed * Time.deltaTime));
}
private void CancelFunction()
{
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))  
  m_rb.velocity = 0;
}
```

You can then fill in the `CancelFunction`with every other key and add it to your update. It kinda is the "rough way" to this but try and see if it works.